# R_Sample with probabilities

Tags: r, sample

I am having some problem with understanding the `prob` in `sample`. For example I want to create a sample data set of size 100 with integers 1,2,3 & 4. I am using a probability of 0.1,0.2,0.3 & 0.4 respectively.

> sample1<-sample(1:4,100,replace=T,prob=seq(0.1,0.4,0.1))

So, now I am expecting a sample with integers of 1,2,3 & 4 repeating 10,20,30 & 40 times respectively. But the result is different

```
> table(sample1)
sample1
 1  2  3  4 
 7 24 33 36
```

Can anyone explain this? And what should I do if I want to get the expected results which is

```
> table(sample1)
    sample1
     1  2  3  4 
    10 20 30 40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sample(...)` takes a random sample with probabilities given in `prob=...`, so you will not get *exactly* that proportion every time. On the other hand, the proportions get closer to those specified in `prob` as `n` increases:

```
f <- function(n)sample(1:4,n,replace=T,prob=(1:4)/10)
samples <- lapply(10^(2:6),f)
t(sapply(samples,function(x)c(n=length(x),table(x)/length(x))))
#          n        1        2        3        4
# [1,] 1e+02 0.090000 0.220000 0.260000 0.430000
# [2,] 1e+03 0.076000 0.191000 0.309000 0.424000
# [3,] 1e+04 0.095300 0.200200 0.310100 0.394400
# [4,] 1e+05 0.099720 0.199800 0.302250 0.398230
# [5,] 1e+06 0.099661 0.199995 0.300223 0.400121
```

If you need a random sample with exactly those proportions, use `rep(...)` and randomize the order.

```
g <- function(n) rep(1:4,n*(1:4)/10)[sample(1:n,n)]
samples <- lapply(10^(2:6),g)
t(sapply(samples,function(x)c(n=length(x),table(x)/length(x))))
#          n   1   2   3   4
# [1,] 1e+02 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
# [2,] 1e+03 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
# [3,] 1e+04 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
# [4,] 1e+05 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
# [5,] 1e+06 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

`sample` takes a sample with the specified probabilities.  That implies randomness - you won't get the same result every time.  To do what you want just use rep

```
rep(1:4, 100*seq(0.1,0.4,0.1))
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way to define the size of population from which it takes the sample set?

Comment: The second argument is just telling it how many times to repeat each of the elements of the first argument.  Modifying that might get what you want.  Your probabilities sum to 1 so the modifier of multiplying by 100 should give us something that is 100 (but with rounding it might be off by 1 every now and then).